# Move a hunk of a commit to another commit in a single rebase

Tags: git

Using GIT, I'd like to move a hunk of a commit to a different one, while automatically retaining commit metadata, using a single interactive rebase.

For example, having these 2 commits:

first commit X:

```
  context
+ foo
  context
```

second commit Y:

```
  context
+ bar
  context
+ baz
  context
```

I would like to move the `bar` hunk from commit Y into the previous commit X, without having to manually reset author, committer, log, etc.

The simplest way I can think of requires 2 interactive rebases:

1. First rebase: split Y commit into Z (`bar`) and Y' (`baz`), the last one using `commit -c Y` to retain the metadata.
2. Second rebase: squash X and Z together into X', and leave Y' as is.

Which would leave this result:
first commit X' (same metadata as X):

```
  context
+ foo
  context
+ bar
  context
```

second commit Y' (same metadata as Y):

```
  context
+ baz
  context
```

Comment: You use the word "chunk", but I think the official term might be "hunk". I'm not sure though. Not that important, just wanted to quickly point it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "changeset"? Commit? Or just a set of changes that belong together? Or a change to a single line?

Comment: Ah right, got used to the term "chunk" using darcs. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @sleske I use "changeset" and "commit" interchangeably, always referring to the object created when running your typical "git commit" command. Again, sorry if that's not the proper term, I will edit the question after this is clarified. FTR, "changeset" is used in mercurial, I keep mixing terms from different VCSs.

Comment: @STenyaK git users use the term "commit", so you should stick with that to avoid confusion.

Comment: `I would like to move the bar hunk from commit Y into the previous commit X, without having to manually reset author, committer, log, etc.` Please elaborate. Are the author and committer going to be the same person?

Comment: @Cupcake I'm concerned about keeping metadata identic across edits/rebases, not identic across fields. E.g. importat thing is that `X' author` == `X author`, `X' committer` == `X commiter`, etc. But whether `author` == `committer` is irrelevant. All without human intervention (to avoid transcription mistakes).

Comment: @STenyaK do you want the message of `X` to remain the same, and the message of `Y'` to match the message of `Y`?

Comment: @Cupcake correct, message of X is identic to message of X' too. An easy to understand use case would be having included a hunk in commit Y instead of commit X, by mistake, and wanting to fix it afterwards (rewriting history not being a concern).

Comment: @STenyaK you can do what you're trying to do in a single rebase using mixed or soft resets and interactive patching. I'm a little unclear about the whole meta-data thing though, if I have time later I'll see if I can think about it more. Until then, though, consider clarifying what you want to do with the metadata in the body of your question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure they're both on the same branch. Use `git diff`, `git apply` and `git add --patch`.

```
git rebase -i $theolderofthetwo^ branch-with-X-and-Y
```

(**edit**: had ghastly error in the above, it actually does what it's supposed to now).

Mark the X commit for edit. If the Y commit is older, mark it for edit.

If the Y commit is older,

```
git diff HEAD HEAD^ -- foobarbaz | git apply
git add --patch
git checkout -- foobarbaz
git commit --amend; git rebase --continue
```

In the X commit (wherever it is):

```
git diff Y^! -- foobarbaz  | git apply
git add --patch
git checkout -- foobarbaz
git commit --amend; git rebase --continue
```

If the Y commit is newer, by the time rebase reaches it that hunk is already in X' no edit is necessary, Y' won't have that hunk -- or rather, it *will* have that hunk, it just won't be a diff.edit

---

The author name and date get preserved anyway.

Comment: And if Y is older and the `foo` and `bar` changes are sufficiently close or adjacent, it actually becomes easier because you will get a conflict when `git rebase` attempts to apply X, and then you can recover bar in the conflict resolution, so then you don't need to do anything for X beyond `git add -- foobarbaz` and then `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: what does `foobarbaz` mean in this context?